# Image loading $.Deferred() jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I am quite new to jQuery, and a problem which bugs me is website loading speed, especially when content of website(like images) can be uploaded of any size by the user.

I decided to dig deeper into the field of asynchronous image loading and came up with this code:

For comfort purposes here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2BSvn/6/

Here is code:

```
var images = [
    'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png',
    'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png',
    'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png',
    'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png'
];
function loadImage (images) {

    if (!images.length) {
        return;
    }
    function deferLoading (deferred) {

        var url = images.shift();

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = loaded;
        image.onerror = errored; 
        image.onabort = errored; 

        image.src = url;

        function loaded() {
            unbindEvents();

            deferred.resolve(image);
            deferred.done(function(image) {

            var img = '\<img src="'+image.src+'" width="200" height="200"   alt="sdfsd" />';
            $('body').append(img);


            });



        }
        function errored() {

            unbindEvents();
            deferred.reject(image);

        }
        function unbindEvents() {

            image.onload = null;
            image.onerror = null;
            image.onabort = null;

        }
    };

    var Deferred = $.Deferred(deferLoading);

    loadImage(images);

    return Deferred;
};

loadImage(images);
```

**My problem is:**
Images are all deferred and displayed together in the end.

**What i would like to do is:** 
Display first image, than second, than third and than fourth;

Help is appreciated.I am trying to do this thing whole day today, seems like i just dont get the idea of $.Deferred in jQuery.

**UPDATE:**

My bad i was testing with localfiles, they were all loaded so fast i thought script is not working. I tested with files from the server, and the script works as expected. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var imgs = function (delay) {
    var callback = function () {
           console.log($("img[alt=sdfsd]").size() + " images loaded");
    };
    var images = [
        'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png',
        'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png',
        'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png',
        'http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png'];
    $.when(images).then(function (_imgs) {
        var i = 0;
        var s = setInterval(function () {
            $("<img>", {
                "src": ($("img[alt=sdfsd]").is("*") ? _imgs[++i] : _imgs[i]),
                    "width": "200px",
                    "height": "200px",
                    "alt": "sdfsd"
            })
                .appendTo("body");

            if ($("img[alt=sdfsd]").size() === images.length) {                

                clearInterval(s);
                callback();

            };
        }, delay);

    });
};
imgs(2500);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/67qUJ/

Comment: It doesn't work. i tested it with big sized photos, photos are displayed one after another but with loading effect, i mean slowly. With my method above, all photos even very big ones are displayed instantly on load, without loading photo from top to bottom.

Comment: Does requirement include loading images in sequence, or all at same time ? OP did not appear to include urls of large (greater than 200px) images ? Utilized same urls from original post . larger images may take a lengthier period to load. If possible, could fork jsfiddle , including full sized images (image urls), for viewing display effects at jsfiddle `full screen result` url ?  Thanks

Comment: See these 2 fiddles : 

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/67qUJ/ - your answer

http://jsfiddle.net/VGN4n/2/ - my fiddle

In your case images are loading, and i see them loading, from top to bottom, in second case, images are shown in an instant, i mean first they take time to load, but than they are showed in an instant. 

But i have doubts, that in second scenario, the script waits for ALL of images to load before showing them, and not load first show first, load second show second way. Can you clarify this moment please? Am i getting something wrong?